# Removing ListView item with dialog

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to remove a `ListView` item via a dialog however that item (`message`) is created in a separate `onClick()` event:

```
final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence addToast = "Choice added";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, addToast, duration);
        adapter.remove(dMessage);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_choice);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        adapter.add(message);
        toast.show();
        editText.setHint(R.string.edit_another_choice);
        editText.setText(null);
    }
});
```

When I use the dialog `onClick()` I want it to remove the selected `message` which I am trying to do:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Delete choice");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int index = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(index));
            }
        });
```

I can't do `adapter.remove(message);` since `message` has to be created in another method when a button is selected so I tried to use the `getSelectedItemPosition()` method instead but it is throwing an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` I feel like the solution might be an easy fix but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to call getSelectedItemPosition.  You already have the position from the onItemClick arguments.

The IDE auto generated the method signature as this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
```

Instead, change it to this and it'll make more sense

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

I would guess (and you can debug or log to confirm if you're curious), that there is no selected item, so getSelectedItemIndex might be returning -1 to represent "no selection".  That would explain the index out of bounds exception.